# Databinding for programmatically generated views in kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a binding adapter that add views programmatically depending on the data that came back from db.

```
@BindingAdapter("addViews")
fun addViews(view: LinearLayout, fruit: List<Fruits>){
    fruit.forEach{
        val v = View.inflate(view.context, R.layout.item_fruit_layout, null)
        v.text_view_fruit_name.text = it.name
        view.addView(v)
    }
}
```

I am trying to not use setText for the textview since I am using databinding but I don't know how to bind the data using either the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` or anything else. Could anyone tell me if I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: The regular way to show the solution is to provide it as an answer. You are able to answer your own questions and mark them as the correct answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
val v = View.inflate(view.context, R.layout.item_fruit_layout, null)
val binding = ItemFruitLayoutBinding.bind(v)
binding.setVariable(BR.fruit, it)
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_fruit_layout, container, false)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not I am looking for. But because of this I figured it out and I will include my solution in my post.